# module pattern and DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module

I am trying to make a `Module` in which I store some `template` from **HTML**

```
var template = (function($){
    console.log( $("#p_id").html()) //returns undefined   

    var __p = $("#p_id").html();
    var __b = $("#b_id").html(); 

    function switchtemplate(tipo) {
        if(tipo === 'plot')
          return __p;
        else  
              return __b;
    };

    //public members
    return {
        switchtemplate: switchtemplate
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But..If every `private var` inside this `module` gets `undefined` `value`.
I tried to execute it on `document.ready` and it is working, but if I try to call `template` from the extern it `return`s `template is undefined` , unless I execute both `module`s (I have more `module`) and method calling inside one `document.ready`.

How can I avoid to define `module` which can do `dom` manipulation?

Comment: one reason could be the `$("#p_id").html()` are executed before the elements `p_id` is loaded

Comment: Yeah,it's just the issue that I noticed, my question is properly about this.

Comment: Your function does not wait for DOM ready in any way, what you have is just a self invoking function that maps the value of the dollarsign to jQuery within the scope of the function, it has nothing to do with document ready

Comment: And it seems like a very complicated way to do something very simple

Comment: one possible solution can be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5vRUu/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umAXD/

Comment: @adeneo my first approach was this :http://jsfiddle.net/umAXD/ , but I'm trying to convert into Modules pattern , this seems to be a namespace. Am I wrong?

Comment: Javascript doesn't really have namespaces, private/public members etc. like what you'd find in some other languages, but most patterns are really just imitating. What javascript does have is prototyping, which is great, but your code is somewhat of a module pattern, and the code in the fiddle is really an object literal but it's also referred to as namespacing, even if it's basically just a variable.